# Warbler packed Rails app doesn't run on Raspberry-Pi (RPi) Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat7, jruby, raspberry-pi, warbler

When I deploy a Rails app WAR (bundled and packed with Warbler and is working on my local Tomcat on OSX) to my little Raspberry-Pi, I get the following stack trace:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: cannot import class `java.lang.reflect.Modifier' as `Modifier'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:63:in `java_import'
    from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2409:in `map'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:22:in `java_import'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.lang.rb:73:in `ModifierShortcuts'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.lang.rb:72:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085:in `require'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext.rb:1:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085:in `require'
    from file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext.rb:3:in `(root)'

    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:104)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5284)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ArgumentError) cannot import class `java.lang.reflect.Modifier' as `Modifier'
    at RUBY.java_import(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:63)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.map(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2409)
    at RUBY.java_import(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:22)
    at RUBY.ModifierShortcuts(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.lang.rb:73)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext/java.lang.rb:72)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1085)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/MyRailsApp/WEB-INF/lib/jruby-core-complete-1.7.11.jar!/jruby/java/java_ext.rb:3)
```

As you can see, the app was packed using JRuby 1.7 and the runtime and everything should also be included in the WAR. As far as I can read the trace, something is missing or not working.

Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: interesting, seems like quite [something going wrong](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/ruby/jruby/java/java_ext/java.lang.rb#L73). could you share what your JVM looks like e.g. `java -version` ?

Comment: checked **ejdk-8-fcs-b132-linux-arm-sflt-03_mar_2014** and it should work - there's probably an exception getting hidden here that is Java SE Embed specific. would be interesting to know if it bahves the same on Java SE 8 Embedded ... although it seems significantly [bigger](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html#javase8) in terms of size

Comment: I have just installed the default Raspbian tomcat package. Java -version gives me: 

java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1+rpi1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: I see, in that case I would probably try reporting with JRuby ...